# Vue.js: access global value in template string

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a very basic Vue.js app that looks like this:

**index.html** (just the `<body>` for succinctness)

```
<div id="root"></div>
```

**main.js**

```
var config = {
  title: 'My App',
}

new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  template: '<div>{{ config.title }}</div>',
})
```

This gives me:

```
Property or method "config" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option. 
(found in root instance)
```

I'm guessing it's because Vue is looking for it in the data store rather than `window`. Is there some way to signal that `config` is a global here, or a better way to do this entirely? I suppose I could pass the config object as a prop to my root `Vue` instance, but it seems like only components accept props. Thanks for any insights on this.

Comment: Why don't you just pass it to the Vue instance? `data : { config : config },`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to define your app as follows:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  template: '<div>{{ config.title }}</div>',
  data: function() {
    return {
      config: window.config
    }
  }
})
```

In the above definition, your `this.config` within the root component points to `window.config` - the global variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to pass the *App Name* in as a hard-coded string you can do something like this:

```
var nameMyApp = new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  data: { input: 'My App' },
  computed: {
    whosapp: function () {
      return this.input
    }
  }

})
```

With your html like this:

```
<div id="root">
  <div v-html="whosapp"></div>
</div>
```

Which will pass the value of *input* to the *whosapp* div.

But, if you're looking for something more dynamic, this would be the way to go:

*With the same html as above...*

```
var nameMyApp = new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  data: { input: 'My App' },
```

The initial value is set to My App, which is what will display if not changed through a function call on the method.

```
    methods: {
    update: function(name) {
        this.input = name;
    }
  },
```

Here is where we define a method that, when called, passes in the parameter to update this.input.

```
  computed: {
    whosapp: function () {
      return this.input
    }
  }

})

nameMyApp.update("New Name");
```

And here is where we call the function, giving it the new parameter; making sure that the parameter is a string.

I hope this is what you're looking for.